# Counting the number of lines that pass through a given polygon using R

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, geocoding, spatial

How can I count the number of lines passing through a polygon given the following.

1. I am accessing the polygon from a SpatialPolygonDataFrame (e.g. SpatialPolygon@polygons[[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpu13.png)]])
2. the lines are SpatialLines

[Here is a sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpu13.png)

Comment: Look at the `rgeos` package and its `gIntersects` function.

Answer (score 0):

Let say spdf is an object of class SpatialPolygonDataFrame and sl is an object of class SpatialLines

Try

`libray(rgeos)
 overlap <- over(sl, spdf)
 sum(!is.na(overlap))`

or directly

`libray(rgeos)
 overlap <- length(sl[spdf,])`

Comment: This would also count the lines that touch polygon(s) `spdf`. `gRelate` can help you figure out whether the line passes through.